# Cannot access the URL of my application

Tags: java, openshift, wildfly

Up until a few days ago everything worked fine. Today when i tried accessing my application URL i got a 404 not found. I tried running my application locally on my server and it worked perfectly. What can i do?
**UPDATE**

```
[0m[0m15:05:50,286 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jmx.management.integration (missing) dependents: [service org.wildfly.management.jmx] 
      service jboss.remoting.endpoint.management (missing) dependents: [service jboss.jmx.remoting-connector-ref] 

[0m[31m15:05:50,376 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
[0m[31m15:05:50,385 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "naming")]): java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCTL0157: Operation already complete
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.assertNotComplete(OperationContextImpl.java:1855)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.isRuntimeChangeAllowed(OperationContextImpl.java:1849)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.getServiceTarget(OperationContextImpl.java:726)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationContext.getServiceTarget(ParallelBootOperationContext.java:196)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.subsystem.NamingSubsystemAdd.performBoottime(NamingSubsystemAdd.java:67)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.performBoottime(AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.java:157)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.performRuntime(AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:151)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:890)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

[0mun(JBossThread.java:320)

2016-06-18 15:05:50,194 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ironjacamar.idle-remover: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ironjacamar.idle-remover: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.jca.IdleRemoverService.start(IdleRemoverService.java:53)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1357)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:668)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.idle.IdleRemover.start(IdleRemover.java:137)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.jca.IdleRemoverService.start(IdleRemoverService.java:51)
    ... 5 more

2016-06-18 15:05:50,200 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "jca")]): java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCTL0157: Operation already complete
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.addStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:296)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.addStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:270)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.addStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:259)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationContext.addStep(ParallelBootOperationContext.java:124)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationContext.addStep(ParallelBootOperationContext.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:897)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

2016-06-18 15:05:50,250 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ironjacamar.connection-validator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ironjacamar.connection-validator: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.jca.ConnectionValidatorService.start(ConnectionValidatorService.java:53)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1357)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:668)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.validator.ConnectionValidator.start(ConnectionValidator.java:138)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.jca.ConnectionValidatorService.start(ConnectionValidatorService.java:51)
    ... 5 more

2016-06-18 15:05:50,286 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jmx.management.integration (missing) dependents: [service org.wildfly.management.jmx] 
      service jboss.remoting.endpoint.management (missing) dependents: [service jboss.jmx.remoting-connector-ref] 

2016-06-18 15:05:50,376 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
2016-06-18 15:05:50,385 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "naming")]): java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCTL0157: Operation already complete
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.assertNotComplete(OperationContextImpl.java:1855)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.isRuntimeChangeAllowed(OperationContextImpl.java:1849)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.getServiceTarget(OperationContextImpl.java:726)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationContext.getServiceTarget(ParallelBootOperationContext.java:196)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.subsystem.NamingSubsystemAdd.performBoottime(NamingSubsystemAdd.java:67)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.performBoottime(AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.java:157)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.performRuntime(AbstractBoottimeAddStepHandler.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:151)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:890)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

This is my log that i got back from the server. I tried to google the exceptions but i could not find anything. Can someone pls help? Thank you!

Comment: Check logs. Check your app in the web console.

Comment: I`ve updated my post, but i cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Java is not in my wheel house.  I see out of memory errors.  Did you restart your app?

Comment: Yes, several times..

Comment: Out of memory in your gear/app? Just guessing.

Comment: My db drops every time i close the connection

Comment: What are the memory settings you are starting the server with?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, i haven`t changed anything in the configurations. Nevertheless since yesterday i am able to connect to my website again. I used the rhc app-tidy command but it did not get me far. I'm not sure if i did something or the problem came from openshift.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

can have more than one reason. First, it is possible that you don't have enough memory on your machine. But it is also possible that you have hit some thread limit on your OS. You could check your server for its memory utilisation. Also, you can check the thread limit. For example, on Linux you could try this:

[Check the max thread count for a user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47595/linux-max-threads-count)

[View threads on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/80556/how-do-you-view-all-threads-running-on-linux)